# Till the first friend dies, we think ecstasy impersonal, but then discover that he was the cup from which we drank it, itself as yet unknown

Tags: sentence-meaning

> Till the first friend dies, we think ecstasy impersonal, but then discover that he was the cup from which we drank it, itself as yet unknown

[The Drift Called the Infinite: Emily Dickinson on Making Sense of Loss](https://www.brainpickings.org/2017/07/20/emily-dickinson-mother-death/?utm_source=Brain+Pickings&utm_campaign=e5ab79fdbf-EMAIL_CAMPAIGN_2017_07_21&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_179ffa2629-e5ab79fdbf-237135017&mc_cid=e5ab79fdbf&mc_eid=574d75b283)

My question:does **impersonal** define **ecstasy** as "unknown" and does "itself" refer to "ecstasy"?

Comment: Questions of interpretation of poetry are usually better on a different stack exchange such as https://literature.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @JamesK This is actually a quotation from a letter. It's prose, technically, but might as well be poetry.

Comment: Till the first friend dies, we think ecstasy impersonal, but then discover that he (the friend who died) was the cup from which we drank it (ecstasy), itself (the cup) as yet unknown (not recognized for what it was).

Comment: I see no reason to have closed this question, since it is about how to parse the language, as indicated by the OP's comment.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo agreed. The question should be fine after your latest edit.

Answer (score 2):

Replacing all of the pronouns—except *we*, which has no referent in the sentence, but which probably refers to something like "a group of friends"—with their most likely referents, I get this version of the sentence:

> Till the first friend dies, we think ecstasy [is] impersonal, but then [we] discover that [the now-dead first friend] was the cup from which we drank [ecstasy], [the cup—that is, the friend— being] as yet unknown [as the vessel of ecstasy].

The phrase "as yet unknown" seems to mean "not at that earlier time understood or recognized," and the sense of the sentence seems to be that we (a group of friends) don't realize the extent to which our experience of joy depends on every member of our group of friends, until the first member of the group dies and we feel it as if it were the loss of the vessel of our shared joy.

Answer (score 0):

The original quote was,

> Till the first friend dies, we think ecstasy impersonal, but then discover that he was the cup from which we drank it, itself as yet unknown

We can re-word it to make things somewhat less murky:

> Before our one of our friends dies, we believe that ecstasy is impersonal.
> Shortly after you have a friend die for the first time, you will discover that he was the cup from which we drank it, itself as yet unknown.

My re-wording is still not completely clear, but clearer than the original, relatively speaking.

"he", "it", and "itself" are  all very vague words.

Itself could re replaced with "ecstasy", "impersonal", or "friend".

I am not sure which of the following is most consistent with the original:

- We discover that our friend was the cup from which we drank ecstasy, <the impersonal as yet unknown
- We discover that ecstasy was the cup from which we drank the impersonal, our friend as yet unknown
- we discover that our friend was the cup from which we drank ecstasy, ecstasy as yet unknown

Answer (score 0):

The following is a less ambiguous translation:

> Before I experienced the death of a friend, I believed that happiness was impersonal.
> After my friend died, I discovered that he was the cup from which I drank happiness.
> Before his death, I did not know that my friend was the the vessel of my ecstasy (the source of my happiness)

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'll take a stab at it. Here's my interpretation:

> Until we lose our first friend to death, we think that ecstasy is an impersonal, random experience, but then we discover that our close friend was the source of our ecstasy, and that we didn't at the time know or appreciate what true ecstasy was.

Answer (score -1):

**Impersonal** modifies **ecstasy**. **Itself** seems to be the cup.